# Malayalam unicode support in terminal - Ubuntu 16.04 minimal

Tags: command-line, unicode, malayalam

I have installed `youtube-viewer` in my Ubuntu 16.04 minimal desktop. 
When I am running `youtube-viewer`, malayalam results are not showing correctly as you can see in the screenshot below. I have tried the same in rxvt-unicode with malayalam fonts installed, but no difference at all. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install Google Noto Fonts for Malayalam. That might help

https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-mlym

Also, do you have any Malayalam fonts installed already ?

SMC has a repo for Ubuntu. See if it makes any difference

https://launchpad.net/~smcproject/+archive/ubuntu/repo

Comment: Yes, I have installed fonts already.